# Rails: Avoiding caching on assocation count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following piece of Rails code:

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base  
  # ...
  def validate_books_have_authors
    self.books.each do |book|
      # Urghh...caching book.authors unless we call directly
      # puts book.authors
      errors[:books] << t('book.no_authors', :book => book.name) unless book.authors.any?
    end
  end
end
```

On first run, the validator will process correctly...but if I run the same method again, the value for book.authors.any? returns a cached value *unless* I uncomment that puts book.authors line

So, simple question really: how do I ensure the value of book.authors.any? isn't cached?

Comment: i think you should use proc

Comment: Hi Nick...could you elaborate on that?

Comment: this might help http://augustl.com/blog/2008/procs_blocks_and_anonymous_functions/

Comment: try `self.books(true).each`. It will always generate database query.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to either use `exists?` or call `count` and check that the result is greater than zero.

Counting is usually a little slower as it requires more work from the database to establish a precise count.

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but both are still bound to the outdated cache.

Answer (score 0):

For reference: I fixed this by changing .any? to .present?

Comment: Hi Sybarite - I did, but the spec I was using to test the functionality was stubbed - it didn't touch the DB, hence the spec still failed.

Comment: Ok. No problem.. I was just curious to know the results. :)